# mod_proxy apache loading error - ap_timeout_parameter_parse

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-proxy

After compiling mod_proxy like so:
/wm/httpd/bin/apxs -i -a -c mod_proxy.c proxy_util.c

I get this error when attempting to start apache:

```
su -c "/etc/init.d/httpd restart" 
Password: 
Stopping httpd:              [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 60 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load  /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so: undefined symbol: ap_timeout_parameter_parse
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when a chunk of code (in this case, the `mod_proxy` module) looks for the symbol `ap_timeout_parameter_parse` and can't find it in either the apache core or any loaded modules.

You should try restarting apache by hand; if that doesn't work, recompile apache and all its modules (including `mod_proxy`), then restart it again. `ap_timeout_parameter_parse` exists in the core, so you should get `mod_proxy` working again by just recompiling apache; however, it's better to recompile everything so your modules and core are consistent with each other.